# Can I meditate for more than 23 hours?

Tags: the-witcher-3

In the Witcher 3, during choosing the time for meditation, is there any way I can meditate for more than 23 hours? I noticed if I move the slider further than 23 hours, it starts counting again from 1 hour.

I need to meditate for 5 days or more for certain things, such as money and restock of supplies for vendors etc. So was wondering if there was a way to meditate for 5 days straight rather than going 23 hours at a time.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There is no way to meditate more than 23 hours.

What i advice you to do is just meditate multiple times, until you have reached the point in time that you wanted to reach.